# SQL - Is running RECONFIGURE dangerous in production

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to run the following on my production server:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;  
GO  

RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

My question is, Is there any danger running this command in a production environment. Would it drop any connection and would end users notice any down time?

Comment: Allowing for cmd shell definetly poses many threats. But not a down time for it's execution.

Comment: Allowing cmd shell is so I can write to a text file and I haven't found another way other than this. Perhaps i'll continue researching to find alternatives to opening xp_cmdshell. Thanks for pointing it out though Serg

Comment: @RichardThompson, you'll need a SQLCLR assembly marked for `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` to create the file directly from T-SQL without xp_cmdshell. I suggest doing this via a client app rather than a T-SQL interface but you could create an SSIS package and launch via the SSISDB catalog procs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878160.aspx).

Comment: No, there is no downtime, and turning on `xp_cmdshell` isn't dangerous in and of itself. That only comes with the inevitable next step, when you grant accounts permission to actually use it. Secure use of `xp_cmdshell` is possible, but requires care. As Dan has pointed out, though, when you find yourself wanting to call applications from SQL Server, you usually want a client application to take the initiative instead. If you want a text file with data from the database, write an application to fetch the data. This can be a simple as a batch file with `sqlcmd`. Don't make the database push it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There will be no downtime,

> RECONFIGURE specifies that **if the configuration setting does not require a server stop and restart**, the currently running value should be updated

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reconfigure-transact-sql

If you use 'with override' it can cause problems.  i.e. it will allow you to change settings that you shouldn't change without a restart.

The usual proviso applies, you should test this in a test environment before using it in production.